Problem to access R Repo on NEXUS using Rscript
I've problems to access a local hosted R Proxy Repo on our NEXUS 3.52.0-01 using Rscript from my RHEL9 VM.
I'm able to access the package list via curl.
$ curl https://<NEXUS_HOST>/repository/r-proxy/src/contrib/PACKAGES | head -n 20

Package: A3
Version: 1.0.0
Depends: R (>= 2.15.0), xtable, pbapply
Suggests: randomForest, e1071
NeedsCompilation: no
License: GPL (>= 2)

Package: AalenJohansen
Version: 1.0
Suggests: knitr, rmarkdown
NeedsCompilation: no
License: GPL (>= 2)

Package: AATtools
Version: 0.0.3
Depends: R (>= 3.6.0)
Imports: magrittr, dplyr, doParallel, foreach
NeedsCompilation: no
License: GPL-3

If I try to download one of the listed packages using Rscript with install.packages I got following error message.
$ /usr/bin/Rscript --slave --no-save --no-restore-history -e 'install.packages("A3", lib="<PATH_TO_USER_LIB>", repos="https://<NEXUS_HOST>/repository/r-proxy")'
Warning: unable to access index for repository https://<NEXUS_HOST>/repository/r-proxy/src/contrib:
  cannot open URL 'https://<NEXUS_HOST>/repository/r-proxy/src/contrib/PACKAGES'
Warning message:
package ‘A3’ is not available for this version of R

A version of this package for your version of R might be available elsewhere,
see the ideas at
https://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/r-patched/R-admin.html#Installing-packages

I could imagine that I need to tell Rscript that the correct certificate is being used. But I’m not sure how to tell Rscript to use a specific certificate.
On the other hand, I think RScript uses the same system's trust store as curl. This would again indicate that there is no certificate problem.

First you should verify that the Rscript requests do reach your Nexus by increasing Nexus's logging level as described here
If your Nexus runs behind a reverse proxy, check the proxies rules for handling the Rscript requests. Probably the reverse proxy containes rules for handling Maven requests (*.jar, *.sha1, *.zip etc). R-artifacts come in *.tgz format. An appropriate rule may be missing.
